# Magento2 - External Image URL to product image

Tags: magento2, product-images, magento2-api

I'm using `Magento2.3.4` and there is an `API` response that sends me `JSON`  to add a new product image:

```
{
  "base_image"  : [{"type":"url","value":"http://imgur.com/base_image.png"}],
  "small_image" : [{"type":"url","value":"http://imgur.com/small_image.png"}],
  "thumbnail"   : [{"type":"url","value":"http://imgur.com/thumbnail.png"}],
  "gallery"     : [
                   {"type":"url","value":"http://imgur.com/gallery_1.jpg"},
                   {"type":"url","value":"http://imgur.com/gallery_2.jpg"}, 
                  ]
}
```

as you can see from the `json` above , there is an `external url` that I need to save as product images, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure about the requirement but maybe you can convert this JSON response to CSV file and then use `Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import` class to import this csv. This way, you will be using Magento import functionality and that will handle the external image url itself.

```
$import_file = pathinfo($import_path);
    /** @var \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import $import */
    $import = $this->importFactory->create();
    $import->setData(
        [
            'entity' => \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE,
            'behavior' => \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_ADD_UPDATE,
            'validation_strategy' => \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\ErrorProcessing\ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface::VALIDATION_STRATEGY_SKIP_ERRORS,
        ]
    );

    $read_file = $this->readFactory->create($import_file['dirname']);
    $csvSource = $this->csvFactory->create(
        [
            'file' => $import_file['basename'],
            'directory' => $read_file,
        ]
    );

    $validate = $import->validateSource($csvSource);
    if (!$validate) {
        $this->logger->error('Unable to validate the CSV.');
    }

    $result = $import->importSource();
```